# My iPhone sets alarms for me without my permission

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

I'm having a strange problem, and it's been happening for many months, from iOS 8 to 10.1, much more recently in iOS 10 however.

Here are the issues that I have been having:

- I set an alarm (say, 7:00am) my iPhone goes off at that time, all well and good. However, when I snooze the alarm, get up, turn off the alarm (with the switch in the Clock app) it will still go off as if I didn't switch it off.
- If I delete an alarm, it will magically ring a few days later even though it is not shown in the Clock app (today I got up at 8:00am, to find out that the alarm wasn't even there!)
- On rare occasions, I will set alarms and they don't go off
- When I ask siri to "delete all alarms" it says "Do you want to delete all alarms?" I tried saying "yes" "confirm", "ok" and tried clicking on the confirm button but siri says "Nothing to confirm"

Things I have tried:

- deleting all alarms
- reinstalling iOS 10 (complete reformat and restore from iCloud)
- force quitting the clock app and reopening it
- rebooting several times
- set it into silent mode (doesn't seem to change anything)

I have some alarms on a schedule, but since then I have deleted those ones and the issues still persist.

I noticed that the changelog for iOS 10.2 says that some users were having problems with alarms not ringing, which might have caused my alarms to ring too often.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clicked on the "Bedtime" tab and found out that there was a 6:30am alarm set there. As for the other alarms, well, it's possible they were set via the bedtime tab as well.